# How to identify the .so file used by Android for system functions?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, shared-libraries

I'm looking to identify which .so file contains the method 'connect' used to establish a network connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connect` function, like most low level system functions, is in `libc.so`.

The proper tools for investigating the contents of binaries (like nm, objdump) are not installed by default on Android, but you can yet use `strings`:

```
strings /system/lib/libc.so | grep connect
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question. My objective is to hook the call to connect in Android. How can I identify which .so makes the call to connect? For example, in Lollipop, webviewchromium.so calls connect. How to identify this in other versions?

Comment: who makes the call depends on the app - you might be able to attach to the app with a native debugger, set a break point on `connect`, and investigate the backtrace when it stops - that's what I would do on desktop/server linux, but I don't know so much about android